# kinit using Python subprocess

Tags: python, ssh, subprocess

I'm trying to connect to a remote server via subprocess + ssh to list the files in a directory and print the content of a file in that directory. To do that I need to run kinit as a Python subprocess.Any idea on how to do that? assume the user logged on using their kerberos id and password..

Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to run `kinit` to make the user get a Kerberos ticket, you can just prompt for their password (e.g. using the `getpass` module) and then pass that input to the subprocess.

This looks something like this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

kinit = '/usr/bin/kinit'
kinit_args = [ kinit, '%s@%s' % (userid, realm) ]
kinit = Popen(kinit_args, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
kinit.stdin.write('%s\n' % password)
kinit.wait()
```

This establishes a ticket the usual way, which should be picked up by anything which looks for a Kerberos ticket in the usual way (in the code that fragment is from, it's to authenticate an LDAP connection): https://github.com/jeremyroman/pyceo/blob/master/ceo/ldapi.py

Comment: Is there a way to do this without prompting for the password?

Comment: If you know the password, you can just use it without prompting. You can't get a Kerberos ticket unless you have the password or keytab, as far as I know.

Comment: if you want to avoid include the password in your code, you should create a keytab files for the service principal `kadmin -q "ktadd -k /etc/apache2/http.keytab HTTP/www.example.com"` and use that with `kinit -k -t /etc/apache2/http.keytab HTTP/www.example.com`  to request a TGT